# MySQL query with LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have problem with this query.

```
SELECT id, zadane, firma, nazov, miesto, ukoncenie
FROM praca
WHERE LOWER( nazov ) LIKE '%administratívny pracovník, referent%'
AND potvrdena =1
AND LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%bratislavský kraj%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%bratislava%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%malacky%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%pezinok%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%senec%'
ORDER BY nazov
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It's supposed to display only records which LOWER(nazov) LIKE something but it still displays everything which contains something from LOWER(miesto).
I'm not sure if I explained it correctly. Srry for my english.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `OR`s in `()`.

```
SELECT id, zadane, firma, nazov, miesto, ukoncenie
FROM praca
WHERE LOWER( nazov ) LIKE '%administratívny pracovník, referent%'
AND potvrdena =1
AND ( 
   LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%bratislavský kraj%'
   OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%bratislava%'
   OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%malacky%'
   OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%pezinok%'
   OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%senec%' 
)
ORDER BY nazov
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, zadane, firma, nazov, miesto, ukoncenie
FROM praca
WHERE LOWER( nazov ) LIKE '%administratívny pracovník, referent%'
AND potvrdena =1
AND( 
   LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%bratislavský kraj%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%bratislava%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%malacky%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%pezinok%'
OR LOWER( miesto ) LIKE '%senec%'
)
ORDER BY nazov
LIMIT 0 , 30
```